# Getting error "Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'Range<Int>'" when using a ForEach loop in a view. (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui

Here is some code:

```
@State var guessedLetters = [" "]()

var body: some View {
     HStack{
          ForEach(guessedLetters){ letter in
               Text("\(letter) ")
          }
     }
 }
```

And this is the error Im getting:
" Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'Range(Int)' "
Can anyone help? I've tried several things but cannot figure out what's going on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 major issues here

1. You don't need `()` at the end of an array if you're initializing it.
2. Provide an `id` in the `ForEach` in this case, the element itself.

```
@State var guessedLetters = [" "]
var body: some View {
     HStack{
        ForEach(guessedLetters, id: \.self) { letter in
               Text("\(letter) ")
          }
     }
 }
```